# Select only data whos not null

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a problem with getting `null` data from my database. Every time I run a query I get `null` data which is stored as `null` in my database table. If a table column has `null` value then I don't want to select that.

I already tried with this query:

```
SELECT col_1,col_2 FROM table where col_1 = 'value' or col_2 = ''
```

If the value is `null` in `col_2` then I want to avoid it... but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Try to add "col_2 IS NOT NULL"

Comment: can add like this col_2 = '' IS NOT NULL ?

Comment: yes, this is the list of operator https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-not-null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `where col_1 = 'value' or col_2 = ''`

As it is, this `OR` expression allows `null` values in `col2`, as long as `col_1` is equal to `'value'`.

You want :

```
where col_2 is not null and (col_1 = 'value' or col_2 = '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT col_1,col_2 FROM table where col_1 = 'value' or col_2 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Some explanation might be helpful. How does your code address the problem?

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.